# How do I resolve this error in Selenium : ERROR: Couldn't keep showing me the page https://www.google.com/

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"))
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

The program kills itself just after working. I expect it to keep showing me google window here

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simply running to the end, and then closes the browser.

Try using the following script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")) 
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

imput("press ENTER to exit\n")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks it solves the above problem but it started creating another problem.[14904:908:0322/083202.456:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [08:32:02.456] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[14904:908:0322/083202.457:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [08:32:02.457] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Comment: That's a known issue, just search for the error message and you'll find some solutions